# How to use Firebase IdToken to generate OAuth Access for Google drive?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-drive-api, google-oauth, nativescript-firebase

**Update**

In my Nativescript-Angular application I'm using `@nativescript/firebase` plugin which uses Firebase authentication and in the scope I have provided `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`.

```
firebase
        .login({
          type: firebase.LoginType.GOOGLE,
          googleOptions: {
            scopes: ["email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"],
          },
        })
        .then((user: firebase.User) => {
          //Firebase ID Token
          const idToken = value.providers[0].token;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
```

While running application, it asked for user login along with user's consent for **Google drive access**. After successful authentication it returns a Firebase Id Token.

In the next step application requires to access user's Google Drive. As I know Google Drive API requires OAuth Access token while application has Firebase Token.

`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files`

**My questions is:** How to generate OAuth Access token which is capable to access user's Google drive?
OR
Is there any alternate solution for this?

Comment: Here is a way to obtain the oauth access token: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73561889/596816

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can determine, the FirebaseNativeScript library's `getAuthToken()` call returns an ID token.

Firebase Authentication users do not necessarily have access to Google Drive. Instead you'll need to use the user's OAuth2 token (the same one that is used to sign in to Firebase) to access Google Drive. In steps, you'll need to:

1. request the additional OAuth scopes needed to access Drive,
2. capture the OAuth token (not a Firebase token) and,
3. use *that* to access Drive.

If you've tried this already, please edit your question to show what you've tried.

Comment: I have provided https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive Scope while calling login(). When I tried to access Google Drive API using returned token, it says 
```{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "authError",
                "message": "Invalid Credentials",
                "locationType": "header",
                "location": "Authorization"
            }
        ],
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Invalid Credentials"
    }
}```
Can you please tell me where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is definitely the solution, but how do you then refresh the accessToken? Do you need to then simply use gapi with a standard token refresh?

Answer (score -1):

It has been resolved. Basically the problem is with `@nativescript/firebase` plugin which is not returning accessToken. I have customised the plugin which is now returning accessToken that I am able to authorise on Google APIs.