# How i get new access token when current access token has expired, google firebase auth?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, access-token, firebase-admin, refresh-token

I use firebase at client and use firebase-admin at server.
At client i use signInWithPopUp to sign in to my web app with google account, then receive accessToken, expirationTime, refreshToken at client.

```
stsTokenManager:{
  accessToken: "eyJhbGciOiJzGcaUzI1JKKIsIzxcXzStpZC... ,
  expirationTime: 1648809531166 ,
  refreshToken: "AIwxAjDfh8_SkckvoSsASxXllMkIX8GBNx...
```

And i use verify function in firebase-admin lib for verify token was send by client, but until token has expired(1h), i can't use this token.
How i get new accesstoken when current access token has expired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to necessarily have to read user's `idToken`, store it anywhere or refresh it yourself. Instead you just need to use [`getIdToken()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#getidtoken) to get user's ID Token. If the token has expired, Firebase SDK will refresh and return a new token or return existing one. You can use `getIdToken()` before every request to your API.

```js
const userToken = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken();

// pass userToken to in the API request
// API request here
```

Comment: so do i need to store token or refresh token on client browser?

Comment: @HTL no, you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to obtain the oauth access token:

```js
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider()
provider.addScope(...)

...

const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result)
console.log(credential.accessToken)
```

I don't know how to refresh that token.