# Firebase Authentification expiresIn (time needed for token to expire )

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

In the response of (`createUserWithEmailAndPassword` or `signInWithEmailAndPassword`)
we have `_tokenResponse.expiresIn` and it's equal to 3600 seconds

How to modify this value to a longer value like  30 days or something like that?

Answer (score 4):

The duration of that token cannot be changed and that does not mean the session has expired. Checkout [Firebase 3.x - Token / Session Expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487283/firebase-3-x-token-session-expiration).

It's just the `access_token` and you can get a new one using the `refresh_token`. Firebase Auth SDK does this for you under the hood. You just need to call `getIdToken()` and you get a valid token every time. Checkout [How i get new access token when current access token has expired, google firebase auth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71705195/how-i-get-new-access-token-when-current-access-token-has-expired-google-firebas) for more information.

If you use the [session cookies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies), there you can specify the validity of the token set in the cookie (up to 14 days) but that's ideal for server side rendered web apps.

Comment: Should I call getIdToken() every I make a request to my backend, to make sure it is always fresh?

Comment: @JuanPerez yes, you can. The SDK will automatically refresh the token behind the scenes only when refreshed.